# Is it possible to not load a control that's already defined in the mark up

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have a multipurpose page, depending on a `QueryString` parameter I can tell how this page is going to be used now.

The difference between the various purposes or functions of this page will result in a little difference of controls shown.

so I was thinking to optimize the page I could try to detect the current function of the page in an early even of the page's life cycle and "remove" (remove, hide, whatever works I really dunno and this is my question in the first place) the unnecessary controls and win a bit lighter and faster page.

What do you think =) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works fine. You can use the `Visible` property on web controls to remove them from the output, if you set it to false, it won't render any HTML code to the page.

If you have a bunch of elements to keep from rendering (or a plain HTML element, which doesn't have the `Visible` property), you can put a `PlaceHolder` control around them, and use the `Visible` property on that.

Comment: . Thanks for your answer. although if you have an article or something from a famous/trusted website or a prove to show that it won't load the controls or bare the page the stateview of the unnecessary controls that would be great .. and of course no offense intended =)

Comment: @rrrr, Lol +1 :D .. there's no fault in double checking something that's related to your career ;)

Comment: @IKashef: Good point about the ViewState. If the controls have previously contained data (or perhaps even otherwise, depending on the control) they may still put data in the ViewState while being invisible. You may be able to disable ViewState for the controls that you hide to prevent that.